# When accessing the current state inside a React Hook's setState() call, is the prevState variable a copy or a direct reference to the state object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Imagine that we need to update some property inside a object in state. Also we need to keep other properties intact.

`const [myState,setMyState] = React.useState({propA: 'FOO'})`

I usually do something like this:

```
function update() {
  setMyState((prevState) => {
    // IS 'prevState' A SHALLOW COPY OR A DIRECT REFERENCE TO THE SAME OBJECT
  });
}
```

**QUESTION**

Is `prevState` a shallow copy or a direct reference to the same object? If it's a direct reference, is basically the very same object, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you can see from the snippet below `prevState` **IS a direct reference to the current state object.** In other words, since objects are basically references, `prevState` is the very same object as the current state.

You can see that behavior in the snippet below:

**Note:** See that when you update the state without shallow copying the state, you change the state object, but you don't trigger a re-render, because react only checks the object reference, and that remains the same, because you return the very same object, with the very same reference to it.

```js
function App() {
  
  const[myState,setMyState] = React.useState({propA: 'FOO'});
  
  function handleClick() {
    console.clear();
    setMyState((prevState) => {
      console.log('myState: ' + JSON.stringify(myState));
      console.log('prevState: ' + JSON.stringify(prevState));
      console.log('Are "myState" and "prevState" the very same object: ' + JSON.stringify(prevState === myState));
      const shallowCopy = {...prevState}
      console.log('shallowCopy of prevState: ' + JSON.stringify(shallowCopy));
      console.log('Are "shallowCopy" and "prevState" the very same object: ' + JSON.stringify(shallowCopy === myState));
      return prevState;
    });
  }
  
  function updateWithShallowCopy() {
    setMyState((prevState)=>{
      const shallowCopy = {...prevState};
      shallowCopy.propA = 'BAR<-------------------------------------';
      return shallowCopy;
    });
  }
  
  function updateWithoutShallowCopy() {
    setMyState((prevState)=>{
      prevState.propA = 'BAR';
      return prevState;
    });
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>{myState.propA}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to inspect</button>
      <button onClick={updateWithoutShallowCopy}>Update WITHOUT shallow copy</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click to inspect</button>
      <button onClick={updateWithShallowCopy}>Update WITH shallow copy</button>
      <div>Click in all buttons in order from left to right</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```